# How do I declare a static phf::Map variable that maps string slices to functions with almost identical signatures in Rust?

Tags: generics, rust, static, hashmap, function-pointers

I have a need to declare a static `phf::Map` variable to map certain string slices to some functions (with almost identical signatures). The task revealed itself to be harder than expected ...

After battling for a while, I came out with this simplified version of the code (see below), in which I managed to get rid of the warning for the first entry in the phf::Map, but I am now stuck because the second function returns a serde_yaml::Error ...

I thought of using a generic instead of the serde_json::Error, in the function pointer, but this does not seem possible :

`phf::Map<&str, fn<E: std::error::Error>(File) -> Result<Config, E>>`

`function pointer types may not have generic`.

At this point the only solution I see is to wrap each of the serde functions in functions with an identical signature, which would involve creating a common error type or an enum and writing two more functions ... and I'd like to avoid that. Given my limited Rust experience, I thought there might just be a neat trick that I am not aware of ...

Below is a snippet that represents what I am trying to achieve and the associated compiler error.

Please note that I am not looking for alternative solutions like pattern matching and lazy evaluations.

Please also note that the code might need other fixes but I am only interested in the one I have just described.

```
use phf::phf_map;
use std::fs::File;
use std::path::Path;


type Config = Vec<String>;


static loaders: phf::Map<&str, fn(File) -> Result<Config, serde_json::Error>> = phf_map! {
    "json" => serde_json::from_reader,
    "yaml" => serde_yaml::from_reader,
};


fn load<P: AsRef<Path>, E: std::error::Error>(filepath: P) -> Result<Config, E>{

    let extension = filepath.as_ref().extension().unwrap().to_str().unwrap();

    match loaders.get(extension) {

        Some(loader) => {

            let reader = File::open(filepath).unwrap();
            loader(reader)

        },

        None => panic!("Invalide extension"),

    }

}


fn main() {
    let filepath = Path::new("conf.json");

    let conf = load(filepath);

    println!("{:?}", conf)
}
```

Here is a snippet of the compiler error. The one that is the subject of the question is the first one.

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/main.rs:113:15
    |
113 |     "yaml" => serde_yaml::from_reader,
    |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected fn pointer, found fn item
    |
    = note: expected fn pointer `fn(File) -> Result<Vec<std::string::String>, serde_json::Error>`
                  found fn item `fn(_) -> Result<_, serde_yaml::Error> {serde_yaml::from_reader::<_, _>}`
    = note: when the arguments and return types match, functions can be coerced to function pointers

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/main.rs:126:13
    |
117 | fn load<P: AsRef<Path>, E: std::error::Error>(filepath: P) -> Result<Config, E>{
    |                         - this type parameter                 ----------------- expected `Result<Vec<std::string::String>, E>` because of return type
...
126 |             loader(reader)
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `Result<Vec<String>, E>`, found `Result<Vec<String>, Error>`
    |
    = note: expected enum `Result<_, E>`
               found enum `Result<_, serde_json::Error>`

error[E0282]: type annotations needed
   --> src/main.rs:140:16
    |
140 |     let conf = load(filepath);
    |                ^^^^ cannot infer type of the type parameter `E` declared on the function `load`
    |
help: consider specifying the generic arguments
    |
140 |     let conf = load::<&Path, E>(filepath);
    |                    ++++++++++++
```

Comment: When you'll call the functions, what error type will you get?

Comment: At this point either a serde_json::Error or a serde_yaml::Error.

Comment: Then you need to declare an enum with these types as variants, and wrap those functions with functions returning it.

Answer (score 2):

There's no additional trick you can use here, the signatures of the functions must match. The only recommendation I can really make is to use a closure (which can implicitly coerce to a function pointer if it doesn't capture any environment) and normalize the error handling within each:

```
static LOADERS: phf::Map<&str, fn(File) -> Config> = phf_map! {
    "json" => |file| serde_json::from_reader(file).unwrap(),
    "yaml" => |file| serde_yaml::from_reader(file).unwrap(),
};
```

If an error has to be propagated, then they *must* be normalized into the same type: either by crafting an enum with variants for both, by mapping to a dummy error, or a dynamic error like `Box<dyn Error>`.

---

Here's a version using `Box<dyn Error>` instead of `.unwrap()`:

```
use std::error::Error;

static loaders: phf::Map<&str, fn(File) -> Result<Config, Box<dyn Error>>> = phf_map! {
    "json" => |file| Ok(serde_json::from_reader(file)?),
    "yaml" => |file| Ok(serde_yaml::from_reader(file)?),
};
```

Comment: On that note, I have tried to use a dynamic error in the function pointer, but I could not manage to make it work ... Would you mind sharing a short snippet like above ?

Comment: Should have figured out this one :facepalm:
Thanks a bunch !